# Eclipse doesn't see JavaFX properties in css file, "unknown property"

Tags: java, css, eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

I installed Eclipse and downloaded the OpenJFX SDK. But the problem is that Eclipse marks all -fx- properties in the .css file as warning and writes "unknown property". My JavaFX projects compile and run fine - I followed the instructions on the official JavaFX website. But CSS auto-completion has no properties. In addition, when I add the JavaFX SDK Library to the Build Path, it does not appear in Project Explorer, maybe this is due. Also I have installed e(fx)clipse. 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: does this answer your question ? https://github.com/eclipse-efx/efxclipse-eclipse/issues/75

Comment: @NagarajKandoor, via this link no answer present, only question with the same problem as I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Delete e(fx)clipse plugin; try to install again from

http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.6.0/site

https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-nightly/site

, probably you will be noticed that due unsatisfied dependencies version will be automatically downgraded (3.6.0 -> 3.5.7 in my case). If so, install m2e support from same repository:
[image]